# How does Scala resolve generic types automatically?

Tags: scala, generics

Please consider the following 2 lines of code:

```
def foo[F[B],A](fa: F[A]): String = fa.toString
println(foo(10))
```

It prints `10`. What I wonder, is how it even compiles. I am trying to understand how Scala resolves the generics here. I mean, what are A, B, and F?

When looking at Intellij, it seems like 10 is converted from a Scala Int, to a Java Integer. But I don't know how the Java Integer is converted to any F[A] (Java Integer is not a generic type), as `foo` expects to receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how the Java Integer is converted to any F[A](Java Integer is not generic type), as foo expects to receive.

Java `Integer` is subtype of `Comparable[Integer]`

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```

Scala 2.13 infers `F = Any` and `A = Nothing`

```
scala> def foo[F[_],A](fa: F[A]) = fa
def foo[F[_], A](fa: F[A]): F[A]

scala> foo(10) // print
foo[Any, Nothing](10) // : Any
scala> foo(10)
val res9: Any = 10
```

This inference happens because of the presence of implicit conversion

```
implicit def int2Integer(x: Int): java.lang.Integer = x.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer]
```

If we hide this conversion it will not compile

```
scala> implicit val int2Integer = null
val int2Integer: Null = null

scala> foo(10)
       ^
       error: no type parameters for method foo: (fa: F[A]): F[A] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Int)
        --- because ---
       argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
        found   : 10
        required: ?F[?A]
           ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : Int(10)
        required: F[A]
```

However note despite the fact that `int2Integer` made it compile, the implicit conversion did not actually take place (which might be a bug)

```
scala> foo(10)
val res9: Any = 10
```

where `res9` should have been typed as `Comparable[Integer]` instead of `Any`.

Scala 3 (Dotty) infers `F = Comparable` and `A = Integer` as per `-Xprint:typer`

```
foo[Comparable, Integer](int2Integer(10))
```

and the implicit conversion is indeed applied

```
Starting dotty REPL...
scala> def foo[F[_],A](fa: F[A]) = fa
def foo[F[_$1], A](fa: F[A]): F[A]

scala> foo(10)
val res0: Comparable[Integer] = 10
```

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/12NUbkX6p4xOO4/giphy.gif

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Scala 2.12 or previous, there is an implicit conversion from `Int` to `RichInt` in order to provide additional methods on Java's `Int`.

The definition looks like

```
final class RichInt extends AnyVal with ScalaNumberProxy[Int] with RangedProxy[Int]
```

So here `F[A]` could be `ScalaNumberProxy[A] with RangedProxy[A]` and `B` would be `Int`. Here is an explicit example using only `ScalaNumberProxy` for simplicity.

```scala
import scala.runtime.ScalaNumberProxy
def foo[F[B],A](fa: F[A]): String = fa.toString
println(foo[ScalaNumberProxy, Int](10))
```

If using Scala 2.13+, `RichInt` appears to have been renamed, but there is certainly a similar implicit conversion that applies.

Comment: I am using scala 2.12 . If you suggest `foo[RichInt, Int](10)`, that doesn't work. But mainly what I want to understand is the default generics, that Scala uses, not random types that can do the work.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting something like `foo[ScalaNumberProxy, Int]`, but it's actually more complex such as `foo[ScalaNumberProxy[A] with RangedProxy[A] forSome { type A }, Int]`. I've edited my answer to show a compilable example.

Comment: Thanks for the update! That actually do work. But that is not what Scala is doing. If you remove the import, the you are missing the `ScalaNumberProxy` type. I am interested to know how scala resolves it. What types are passing there without adding more imports.

Comment: The type does not have to be visible through an import for the compiler to be aware of it and use it, so you only need the import because you are explicitly providing the types.